# First time install CentOS 7 problem

Tags: centos, partition, windows, system-installation, dual-boot

I want to install centOS 7 along side windows 8.1 for this I'm planning to do  partition in a following way.

> /boot - 500MB - Standard Partition
>   /swap - Half of my RAM size
>   /root - 20GB - Standard Partition
>   /home - Rest of my space - Standard Partition

The problem is: if I create /swap first, then I couldn't create Standard Partition anymore. Likewise if I create Standard first, I couldn't create /swap.

> The error message is: Unable to allocate requested partition scheme.

After research, I understand that my MBR disk can not have more than 4 primary partition. Here is the current status of my disk

[image: My Partition]

As per as my understanding, Windows already took 3 primary partition

> System (C)
>   System Reversed (E)
>   Extended Partition (container of Data and AOMEI Recovery Partition)

and CentOS require 2 more Primary Partition: **one for /boot and one for the rest** (correct me this part if I'm wrong)

Now I have no idea what I should do next to fix this problem. Should I change the setup of CentOS partition or do something to reduce the number of Primary Partitions on Windows and how to do this without losing data.

Comment: centos does not require any primary partitions.  linux has no difficulty booting from extended partitions.

Comment: if you want to avoid repartitioning that disk, your best bet is to just have a single partition with /, /boot, /home, and everything else on it (i.e. that 115GB unallocated partition), and use a swap file instead of a swap partition (or don't bother with swap at all).  Alternatively, install Virtual Box and run Centos in a VM.  Yet another alternative is to use LVM (centos installer should offer this automatically) and it will make LVM volumes as needed from that 115GB unallocated partition.

Comment: When I try to set LVM volumes for all my disk, the installer said that "/boot can not be LVM". I don't remember the full sentence exactly. Are there any problems if I remove swap partition? Every tutorial I read on the Internet told me that swap is neccessary :(

Comment: does the centos installer give you the option of not having a /boot partition? e.g. "install on one big filesystem" or words to that effect?   RE: swap - how much RAM do you have, and what do you expect to be using the system for?  btw, you can always use a swapfile - they're a bit slower than using a swap partition, but it works.

Comment: swap is useful but not absolutely necessary.  running out of RAM is no different to running out of RAM+SWAP, it just happens a little sooner.

Comment: I tried to exclude the swap partition but the installer displayed warning and told me that I have to include it in other to continue. If I exclude the /boot then it also display "/boot must not be LVM".

Comment: can you get a shell on the centos installer? (i'm not terribly familiar with it, i usually install debian).  Or do you have a bootable rescue CD or USB flash drive?  anyway, whichever way you can get a shell, can you run `fdisk` in it and replace that nearly useless graphical partition list and replace it with useful text with partition and device names?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I found a solution for above problem. I moved the unallocated partition (the one with black bar in my picture) into the Extended Partition, so it became Free Space. And now I can install CentOS on it.

Comment: good news.  you should write that up as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the way I solved this problem:

Move 115 GB unallocated (the one with black bar) into the Extended Partition. Then it would become freespace (with green bar). Now you can install CentOS on this free partition. I used EaseUS to move the partition.

Before partition format (not working):

> System Reversed (E)
>   **Unallocated Space**
>   System (C)
>   Extended Partition (container of Data, AOMEI Recovery Partition)

Working partition format:

> System Reversed (E)
>   System (C)
>   Extended Partition (container of Data, AOMEI Recovery Partition, **Free space**)

Answer (score 0):

To circumvent the 4 primary partitions limit, you can create an extended partition in lieu of a primary partition, and then split it in four logical partitions (`/`, `/boot`, `/swap`, and `/home`).

Also, in the CentOS installer, choose the option to re-format these partitions (except the swap of course). It solved the problem for me when I had the same error message.